# How can I convert an RDD of type [String, String] to RDD of type [Int,Int] in Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

All the existing answers to similar problems are in Scala, but I am using python.

Specifically I am trying to convert `['1,-1', '2,-2']` to `[[1,-1],[2,-2]]`

`myrdd.map(lambda x: x.split(',')).map(lambda x: int(x[0]),int(x[1]))` gives me error.

Edit: I am working with RDDs. The example is to illustrate the contents of the RDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have posted the error message here. I believe it is

> NameError: name 'x' is not defined

This comes from a syntax error in your second lambda. You have to return a list or a tupel:

```
myrdd.map(lambda x: x.split(',')).map(lambda x: [int(x[0]),int(x[1])])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
lista=['1,-1', '2,-2'] 

final_list=[ [int(i[:i.find(',')]), int(i[i.find(',')+1:])] for i in lista ]
            #add the first integer  #add the second integer #, both inside a list, for every item in lista 
print(final_list)
```

Output:

```py
[[1, -1], [2, -2]]
```

Edit: Apparently, this solution only works with lists, but this is all I know for now.

Comment: i am working with RDDs, not lists. can you suggest map to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Parse each element in data through split and apply a lambda to cast to int

```py
data = ['1,-1', '2,-2']
result = [map(lambda i: int(i), element.split(",")) for element in data]
#[[1, -1], [2, -2]]
```

EDIT:

```py
data = RDDstuff
result = [data.flatMapmap(lambda i: int(i), element.split(",")))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from the fact that in your last `map`, you're not returning a tuple in the lambda function. Instead, `int(x[1])` acts as the second parameter to your `map` method. This is why you get `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`

```
myrdd = sc.parallelize(['1,-1', '2,-2'])
myrdd2 = myrdd.map(lambda x: x.split(','))
myrdd3 = myrdd2.map(lambda x: [int(x[0]), int(x[1])])
print(myrdd3.take(2))

[[1, -1], [2, -2]]
```